# Transforming a String in a Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm having a little question here. I'm doing a login with a form, sending strings to a php, to return to me the final answer, "Error" or "OK".

But, i need to php returns a little bit more than it, like a name and etc, and i want to display this name in a label. So, for this, i'll need a array, correct?

So, how can i do this?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = 
[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/dev/mcomm/login.php"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email=%@&pass=%@", email.text, senha.text];

[request setValue:[NSString 
                   stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]] 
 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString 
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] 
 initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


//get response
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;  
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];  
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];  
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it most situations, you would expect the response to be in [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml) or [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

If you have control, access to the API I would suggest you try and go that route instead of an Array